# Custom shape Android

Tags: android

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh2oe.png)[![ListView][2]][2].

I am developing an app. I have mentioned the link please guide how to make this shape Well i am share also code of the shape.

[[2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/drCPG.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh2oe.png)

Comment: here is the code of the  shape<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:left="12dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>

Answer (score 0):

Top part can be just a ImageView with static image.

```
...
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/above_list_view_image_view_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/above_list_view_image_view_height"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listView"
    android:src="@drawable/above_list_view_drawable"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
...
/>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_view_height"
...
/>
...
```

Bottom parts can be just ImageViews with static image inside ListView items

ListView item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/above_list_view_image_view_width"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLineWithDotInCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/line_woth_dot_in_center_drawable"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewContent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewLineWIthDotInCenter"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewLineWIthDotInCenter"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewLineWIthDotInCenter"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewLineWIthDotInCenter"
        android:id="@+id/view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

View with id - `listViewContent` - place where content of listview should be placed

It is not very good way to solve this issue if we think about supporting this in future. But it definitely will work.

Comment: Hi Denis, First of all thanxs for reply denis can you please guide how I connect image with listview in below picture.                                        http://i.stack.imgur.com/drCPG1.png

Comment: Are you asking about image inside (ListView item)?
If so - if image is (png) you can for example make it's height equal to listItem height.
mdpi height = listItemHeight*1
hdpi height = listItemHeight*1.5
xhdpi height = listItemHeight*1.5
etc.